# How to use case statement in Django query

Tags: python, django

I am working on project where i have to convert PostgreSQL queries to Django queries. My question is how to use

```
select id,name, address_1, address_2, city,county,postcode,
        case when fuel = 't' then 'Yes'
        when fuel is null then 'No' else 'No' end as fuel,
        case when food = 't' then 'Yes'
        when food is null then 'No' else 'No' end as food,
        case when shower = 't' then 'Yes'
        when shower is null then 'No' else 'No' end as shower,
        case when toils = 't' then 'Yes'
        when toils is null then 'No' else 'No' end as toils,spaces, cost
        from park
        where type_id = 3 and state_id in (1,2)
```

One way to do this using **extra** method like this

```
ModelName.objects.extra(select={"link_id": "case when link_id >0  then -3 else 0 end"})
```

But i think this is not a best way. Is there any other way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: @lanzz i think, that is Database dependent. if i do migrate DB it will not work for new DB

Answer (score 0):

Since none of these values depend on any complex database logic, I would move the logic to Python and simply make them properties on the model.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ... id, name etc ...
    _shower = models.CharField(db_column="shower")

    @property
    def shower(self):
        return 'Yes' if self._shower else 'No'
```

... and so on.